# Does Stack Overflow have an image that I can use to link to it?

Tags: support, images

I'm asking this as my blogroll consists entirely of images and if SO has a nice one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use your ["flair"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair)?

Comment: That doesn't have a blatantly obvious SO link, does it? (I already have the flair)

Comment: @Aviradlg Then you should have mentioned that you already know about the flair.